# Unable to add calculated field in schema

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, content-type, list-view, deployment

I just want to display data from another column. So i write following field declaration:

```
<Field ID = "{254BCC65-92DC-4c1b-90CC-8E11E4831CD1}"
      Name="NewName"
      StaticName="NewName"
      DisplayName="Calculated Text"
      Group="$Resources:gh;"
      Type="Calculated"
      Description="A calculated text field based on Custom Single Line of Text."
      Required="FALSE"
      ResultType="Text"
      ShowInNewForm="TRUE"
      ShowInEditForm="TRUE">
    <Formula>=[Measure_Type]</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef ID="{B1F9DE38-0B0D-4F7B-BECF-8C830E8583EC}" Name="Measure_Type"/>
    </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

where measure type is just a text column:

```
<Field ID="{B1F9DE38-0B0D-4F7B-BECF-8C830E8583EC}"
         Name="Measure_Type"
         StaticName="Measure_Type"
         Required="FALSE"
         DisplayName="$Resources:asfasfasf;"
         Group="$Resources:gh;"
         Type="Text" />
```

but when I deploy it it just doesn't create anything, just blank stroke instead of column name:
[image]

when I click I get an error: "cannot display filter value. Filtering is impossible or exeeds a threshold".

Comment: Do you have resource files associated with those entries ? (DisplayName="$Resources:asfasfasf;")

Comment: Of course, it works for text field type.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would remove the "$Resources" part in the Display Name of your definitions (if you don't use resource files).

Check this question : [How can I provision a list with a calculated field?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34298/how-can-i-provision-a-list-with-a-calculated-field)

(there is a comment saying that InternalNames are required, and there is this link http://www.hekstra.org/how-to-deploy-a-calculated-field/ saying that Site Column = InternalName and List Column = DisplayName)

The reason seems to be that you have to use the DisplayName in your formula instead on the InternalName.

Comment: Thanks for links, especially for `FormulaDisplayNames`, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I did this.

I agree with taking out the $Resource part.

And yes Formulas use DisplayName as references, I have never used the ID in the FieldRefs

And try it with an existing field first

```
<Field>
...
<Formula>=Title</Formula>
<FieldRefs>
  <FieldRef Name="Title" />
</FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

If this doesn't work your error is not with the Formula

#### Trace from my own CalcMaster App

I add a trace from my CalcMaster App I built some time ago; I use it to work on (new) Calculated Columns.
This is the Schema that works for me:

```
<Field Title="MyColumn" 
    Type="Calculated" 
    JSLink="" 
    Name="MyColumn" 
    DisplayName="MyColumn" 
    DateFormat="0" 
    InternalName="MyColumn" 
    StaticName="MyColumn" 
    Required="FALSE" 
    FilterAble="TRUE" 
    ResultType="Text" 
    Sealed="FALSE" 
    AllowDeletion="TRUE" 
    ReadOnly="TRUE" 
    Viewable="TRUE" 
    Hidden="FALSE" 
    ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" 
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE" 
    ShowInNewForm="FALSE" 
    ShowInListSettings="TRUE" 
    ShowInViewForms="TRUE" 
    Group="_ViewMaster365.com" 
    ClassInfo="ViewMasters" 
    Description="" 
    AuthoringInfo="- editted by the CalcMaster App" 
    Tag="" 
    OutputType="Text" 
    ID="{a8bbf0f1-2b95-461a-9a5f-860ba348850b}" 
    SourceID="{e15e9a9a-127b-4e87-8ba4-731335bb96e5}" 
    ColName="sql_variant4" 
    RowOrdinal="0" 
    Version="1">
<Formula>=Title</Formula>
<FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="Title" />
</FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

*note, I have stuffed some of my own attributes in here, that get ignored by SharePoint; I just don't know exaclty which ones, haven't been in the bowels of this App in some time* :-/

Comment: Well, what should I do if i have localised displayname? Because i tried "Title" and localised value both and they didn't work.